# How can I set a UITapGestureRecognizer's timeout threshold?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` in my iPad app and I want to change the duration it interprets as being short enough for a tap. I want my tap to be recognised on finger-up however long I hold down my finger. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can probably ignore this... I'll just use touchesEnded!

Comment: Actually it turns out I had a UILongPressGestureRecognizer higher up the view chain that was cancelling touches in subviews.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can override the gesture duration the way you want to. However you can use [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which does exactly what you seem to need.

Comment: No, UILongPressGestureRecognizer doesn't do what I need. I want something that behaves on release regardless of how long I hold down my finger before that.